# Passing in String variable to custom user details method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a customer user which has a custom method which takes in a String argument/variable

```
    public String someCustomMethod(String stringVar) {
        return "hello " + stringVar;
    }
```

I am making the following call from my web page and it's working as expected (i.e. printing out "hello world"):

```
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUser().someCustomMethod('world')}">Blah</span>
```

However I have a local variable ${foo} that I would like to pass in instead of hardcoded value. Can this be done? If so - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (in case if you have a local variable **foo** defined in the scope):

```
<span th:text="${#authentication.getPrincipal().getUser().someCustomMethod(foo)}">Blah</span>
```